# Comparing "Unlimited" value to numerical values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a visual comparison between an input vector and my database.However, the input vector or the database may contain the "UL" character, which means, an infinite number. Think of it as your unlimited voice plan, with which you can make an unlimited number of calls.

Here is the code I have used to try to make a visual comparison between "UL" and other numerical values.

```
# d is the database data.frame, with which we want to compare the input vector    
d = structure(list(Type = c("H1", "H2", "H3"),
                       P1 = c(2000L, 1500L, 1000L),
                       P2 = c(60L, 40L, 20L),
                       P3 = c("UL", 3000L, 2000L)),
                  class = "data.frame",
                  row.names = c(NA, -3L))
# d2 is the input vector
    d2 = structure(list(Type = "New_offre", P1 = 1200L, P2 = "UL", P3 = 2000),
                   class = "data.frame",
                   row.names = c(NA, -1L))

    #Check if there are some unlimited values in both d and d2
    y1 <-rbind(d,d2) 
    y <- y1
    if("UL" %in% y$P3){
      max_P3_scale <-  max(as.numeric(y[y$P3!="UL","P3"]))
      y[y$P3=="UL","P3"]= 2*max_P3_scale
    }
    if("UL" %in% y$P2){
      max_P2_scale <-  max(as.numeric(y[y$P2!="UL","P2"]))
      y[y$P2=="UL","P2"]= 2*max_P2_scale
    }
    y <- transform(y,P1=as.numeric(P1),
                   P2=as.numeric(P2),
                   P3=as.numeric(P3))
    d <-  y[1:nrow(d),]
    d2<- y[nrow(d)+1,]
    d %>% gather(var1, current, -Type) %>%
      mutate(new = as.numeric(d2[cbind(rep(1, max(row_number())),
                                       match(var1, names(d2)))]),
             slope = factor(sign(current - new), -1:1)) %>%
      gather(var2, val, -Type, -var1, -slope) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = factor(var2,levels = c("new","current")), y = val, group = 1)) +
      geom_point(aes(fill = var2), shape = 2,size=4) +
      geom_line(aes(colour = slope)) +
      scale_colour_manual(values = c("green","green", "red")) +
      facet_wrap(Type ~ var1,scales = "free")
```

My first attempt was to find if there is "UL" values in P2 and P3. If yes, I try to find the maximum numeric value other than "UL". Then, I replace all "UL" occurrences by this maximum value* 2, so the graphical representations will always show that "UL" is maximum.

The issue with this is that I am not able to differentiate between actual values and "UL" ones.

Here is how my plot looks like using this solution
[image]